# I can't store my data to my database

Tags: sqldataadapter

I have a problem storing my inserted data to my database. When I'm using mdf file that created within of visual studio it won't work. When I'm using dbo file that created from SQL Server 2008 it when I tried to store my inserted data to database it worked well.

I'm using a stored procedure. There was no error occurred. help me pls.

here is the code using sqlcommand:

```
 SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FifthColumn.mdf; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True");
 myConn.Open();
 SqlCommand mycommand = myConn.CreateCommand();
 mycommand.CommandText = "InsertIncident";
 mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NChar, 2, "Country").Value = inputCountry;
 mycommand.Parameters.Add("@IncidentTypeID", SqlDbType.NChar, 2, "Country").Value = inputIncidentTypedID;
 mycommand.Parameters.Add("@AgentID", SqlDbType.NChar, 2, "Country").Value = inputAgentID;
 mycommand.Parameters.Add("@incidentDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = inputID;
 mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 myConn.Close();
```

here is the code using dataadapter:

```
 SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FifthColumn.mdf; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True");
 SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
 myConn.Open();
 myDA.InsertCommand = myConn.CreateCommand();
 myDA.InsertCommand.CommandText = "InsertIncident";
 myDA.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 myDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NChar, 2, "Country").Value = inputCountry;
 myDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IncidentTypeID", SqlDbType.NChar, 2, "Country").Value = inputIncidentTypedID;
 myDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AgentID", SqlDbType.NChar, 2, "Country").Value = inputAgentID;
 myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Saying "it won't work" is rather vague. What exactly happens when you try to use the code? Is there an exception? Is there a bug in the data it inserts?

Comment: **Most likely** it's once again the problem that using the `AttachDbFilename=` method is causing grief; it will create a **copy** of the MDF in your project directory, run your INSERT against that copy, and then you look at some other file (where of course your INSERT isn't present because it wasn't run against that MDF file!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data adapter automatically opens and closes the connection. if you use data adapter, it is unnecessary to open or close the connection.

Second, data adapter is mostly used to fetch the block data from database into a dataset by using fill method of data adapter.

You can use insert command or update command property of data adapter to insert or update any data. They must be assigned to a command object before use.

Comment: yes im using dataset from my dataadpater selectcommand. i found the issue why i cant store it to my database, i forgot to use the executequery method. thanks for the help